# Get child data on firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Under the locations table are some data like name, longitude, latitude, etc. From the result on the table(attached image), instead of using the UID for Location Name, I'll use the "name" of the location which is under that child. The structure of my locations table is on the picture too.

How can I convert the "location_id" to "name" on the table. Instead of me putting the generated ID on the "Location Name", I'll replace it with the actual "name" which is "Luneta Park".

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What is you question?

Comment: How can I convert the "location_id" to "name" on the table. Instead of me putting the generated ID on the "Location Name", I'll replace it with the actual "name" which is "Luneta Park".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it using this:

```
locations.forEach((location) => {
                    if(location.val().location_id ===  histories.val().location_id){
                        locationName = location.val().name;

                    }
                });
```

then pushed it:

```
locationsHistoryCount.push({locationName: location.val().name, historyCount: visitCount});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
locationsHistoryCount.push({
           location_name : location.val().name, 
           historyCount : visitCount
          })
```

You have already used **val()** in **history.val().location_id** so similarly use it for **locations** table too.

Also please post the code instead of snapshot of it.